# How do I disable the Mac App Store notification badge for successful updates?

Tags: catalina, mac-appstore, notifications

Since upgrading to Catalina, the App Store keeps its notification badge despite the app update automatically being installed in the background. Opening the App Store clears this badge and it will stay clear until the next update comes out (where it'll be installed automatically, so the badge is irrelevant).

Questions:

1. Is this the intended behavior, or is this an obscure bug?
2. If it is the intended behavior, does anyone know how to disable this while keeping automatic updates enabled?

Comment: Have you tinkered with the badge display settings in the past, via command line?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it’s a bug (not sure what would make it an “obscure bug”) and you should submit feedback to Apple at https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html

The reson I believe it to be a bug is because if you immediately open the App store, the erroneous badge immediately disappears meaning that upon launch of the app, it correctly indicates that there are none.  In fact, it appears that the badge is “reset” as it checks for updates with the update server.  I have personally seen mine go from 4 updates, then upon opening the App store, the badge disappear and then a few seconds later change to 1 update.

It’s entirely possible that the badge doesn’t update until the next automatic update check.

I don’t believe this to be intended behavior and obviously a nuisance, but it’s nothing that affects functionality.  You can easily fix the badge by opening and closing the App Store app.  I submitted feedback regarding this and I encourage you to do so as well.